# Can I make it mandatory to include at least one of two headers with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

One of my headers is misspelled, and I want to change it while being backwards compatible.

```java
@RequestHeader(value = "Custmer-Key") String customerKey
```

I want to add a header with the correct spelling `Customer-Key`, and make at least one of them mandatory. Any ideas?

Comment: You can implement a request filter https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-add-filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next Approach is to create a annotation OneOf or something. I have used a simpler approach than using Aspect. Using this approach you can validate request param , Requestbody and RequestHeader

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = OneOfValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface OneOf {

    String message() default "";
    String[] value();
}
```

Create a validator class like below.

```
public class OneOfValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OneOf, Object> {

    private String[] fields;
    private String fieldList;

    public void initialize(OneOf annotation) {
        this.fields = annotation.value();
        fieldList = Arrays.toString(fields);
    }

    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(value);
        int matches = countNumberOfMatches(wrapper);
        if (matches > 1) {
            setErrorMessage(context, <your message>);
            return false;
        } else if (matches == 0) {
            setErrorMessage(context, <your message>);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private int countNumberOfMatches(BeanWrapper wrapper) {
        int matches = 0;
        for (String field : fields) {
            Object value = wrapper.getPropertyValue(field);
            boolean isPresent = detectOptionalValue(value);

            if (value != null && isPresent) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }

    private boolean detectOptionalValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Optional) {
            return ((Optional)value).isPresent();
        }
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return StringUtils.hasText((String)value);
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void setErrorMessage(ConstraintValidatorContext context, String template) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(template)
                .addNode(fieldList)
                .addConstraintViolation();
    }
```

In the controller you can create something like below.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "your path")
    public ResponseEntity<HeaderDataDTO> getBuildDetails(@RequestHeader(value = "Custmer-Key") String custmerKey,@RequestHeader(value = "Customer-Key") String customerKey
            ) {
        HeaderDataDTO data = new HeaderDataDTO();
data.setCustomerKey(customerKey);
data.setCustmerKey(custmerKey);
data.validate();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(data,
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

You can define your DTO as below.

```
@Valid
@OneOf(value = {"customerKey", "custmerKey"})
public class HeaderDataDTO extends HeaderValidator {

    private String customerKey;
    private String custmerKey;
//getter and setter
```

HeaderValidator should be like below. Validate method will validate the object.

```
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

public abstract class HeaderValidator {

    public boolean validate() {
        Validator validator = Validation
                .buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<HeaderValidator>> violations = validator.validate(this);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(violations)) {
            throw <your exception>
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a few assumptions here. Each one may or may not be correct in your specific case, but the purpose is to give better context on when such solution is viable and makes sense to use.

1. You have a need to keep backward compatibility (this one is easy... you wrote it)
2. You have a pretty large codebase possibly based on microservices and maintained by several developers and you want to avoid large commits spanning across several teams, centralising the fix in a common shared library that all services are meant to use
3. Your headers are fetched using not just Spring but occasionally also by accessing the request directly
4. You are working in a production application where you want to change as little code as possible as some of its inner workings are difficult to understand

The solution consists into wiring a custom filter, along with its configuration. The filter will swap the `HttpServletRequest` instance with a different one that allows to manipulate the headers.

---

First, create your own filter, as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class HeadersFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String WRONG_HEADER = "Custmer-Key";
    private static final String RIGHT_HEADER = "Customer-Key";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        String newHeaderValue = request.getHeader(RIGHT_HEADER);
        String headerValue;
        if(newHeaderValue != null) {
            headerValue = newHeaderValue;
        }
        else {
            headerValue = request.getHeader(WRONG_HEADER);
        }

        HeadersRewriteHttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeadersRewriteHttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
        requestWrapper.setCustomHeader(WRONG_HEADER, headerValue);

        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }

    public static class HeadersRewriteHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private Map<String, String> customHeaders;

        HeadersRewriteHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
            customHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        }

        void setCustomHeader(String name, String value) {
            customHeaders.put(name, value);
        }

        private String getCustomHeader(String name) {
            return customHeaders.get(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) { // not needed by spring but useful if someone uses this method directly
            String header = super.getHeader(name);
            if(header != null) {
                return header;
            }
            return getCustomHeader(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames()));
            names.addAll(customHeaders.keySet());
            return Collections.enumeration(names);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
            List<String> headers = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
            String customHeader = getCustomHeader(name);
            if(headers.isEmpty() && customHeader != null) {
                headers.add(customHeader);
            }
            return Collections.enumeration(headers);
        }
    }
}
```

Second, wire in the Spring configuration to create an instance of this filter and inject it as necessary.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public HeadersFilter headersFilterBean() {
        return new HeadersFilter();
    }
}
```

That's it. Assuming your application doesn't have quirks preventing this from working (in which case good luck with your debugging), this code will take the contents of both `Customer-Key` and `Custmer-Key`, giving precedence to `Customer-Key` and write them in a fake `Custmer-Key` header. This way you won't have to touch any of the controllers, which should continue to work transparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a interceptor like below.

```
@Component
@Primary
public class HeadersInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage=new ServletServerHttpRequest(request);          
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = inputMessage.getHeaders();
//validation code for header goes here.
//return true if validation is successful    
return true;

    }
 }
```

and add the interceptor to your configuration.

```
 @Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    HeadersInterceptor headersInterceptor;

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(headersInterceptor);
    }
}`
```

Now you can customize your validation in any manner.

Comment: It seems to me that he plans to use the header in a controller. Does your solution allow to read the header using the ```@RequestHeader``` annotation? If not, what does he have to use to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The assumption made by @FilippoPossenti  is correct, I am planning to use it in a controller at a couple of `@PostMapping` handlers.

Comment: This allows @RequestHeader also.. This is only for validating Headers.

Comment: If you want to check only for few controllers you can set these values in a pojo. Annotate it with a custom annotation like OneOf and pass the values. Use aspect around the annotation and validate the values. So if the value for Custmer-key or Customer-key is set then  validation will return success.

Comment: Will add another answer today.